# ¿Como sumar los dígitos de 1 numero, y seguir sumando si esta suma aun tiene mas de 1 dígito?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola amigos buenas tardes, quiero crear un programa que por ejemplo: ingrese un numero = 2424.
Y que el programa sume los 4 dígitos, en este caso seria 2+4+2+4=12.
Pero como pueden ver el 12 sigue siendo un numero de 2 dígitos, y quiero que el programa lo siga sumando para que me arroje el valor de 3.

intente crear uno y si me salio(buscando info en google) pero solo suma hasta la primera parte, osea el 2424, pero no el 12.

```
def suma_de_digitos(numero): 
    numero = str(numero)
    suma = 0
    for i in numero:
        suma += int(i)
    return suma

numero = int(input("Digite un numero que desee que se sume sus digitos: "))

suma_2_digitos = suma_de_digitos(numero)

suma_final = int(suma_2_digitos)

print(suma_2_digitos) #HASTA AQUI SUMA LOS DIGITOS QUE EL USUARIO INGRESA

def ultimo(suma_2_digitos):
    suma_2_digitos = str(suma_2_digitos)
    suma2 = int(suma_2_digitos)
    for y in suma_2_digitos:
        suma2 += int(y)
        return suma2

final = ultimo(suma_2_digitos)

print(final) #AQUI DEBERIA SEGUIR SUMANDO, PERO SOLO AGREGA MAS 1
```

SALIDA:

```
Digite un numero que desee que se sume sus digitos: 2424
12
13
```

Comment: `return numero % 9` 

Answer (score 1):

La causa de tu problema se debe a que la línea `suma2 = int(suma_2_digitos)`, que hace que en todo caso tu segunda función retorne el número que recibe más la suma de sus propios dígitos (para tu ejemplo `12 + (1 + 2) = 15`). El segundo error es que el `return` en esta misma función está dentro del `for` en vez de fuera, esto causa que la función **retorne en la primera iteración del ciclo** (primer dígito), por lo que al final obtienes `12 + 1 = 13`.

Para obtener el resultado que deseas en tu ejemplo concreto basta con llamar dos veces a la función `suma_de_digitos` de forma encadenada:

```
print(suma_de_digitos(suma_de_digitos(numero)))
```

El problema es que a priori no sabes cuantas veces vas a tener que llamar a la función para llegar a la suma de un solo dígito. La opción más simple es usar un ciclo `while` que itere mientras la suma sea un número de más de un dígito (mayor de 9) llamando de forma repetida a la función `suma_de_digitos` pasándole la suma anterior como argumento:

```
def suma_de_digitos(numero):
    numero = str(numero)
    suma = 0
    for i in numero:
        suma += int(i)
    return suma


numero = int(input("Digite un numero que desee que se sume sus digitos: "))

while numero > 9:
    numero = suma_de_digitos(numero)

print(numero)
```

Si quieres puedes usar la función preconstruida `sum` junto a un generador para obtener la suma de los dígitos:

```
def suma_de_digitos_iterativa(numero): 
    while numero > 9:
        numero = sum(int(d) for d in str(numero))
    return numero

numero = int(input("Digite un numero que desee que se sume sus digitos: "))
print(suma_de_digitos_iterativa(numero))
```

Una opción más eficiente que las anteriores es usar el resto de la división entre 10 (modulo) para obtener los dígitos. Esto evita la sobrecarga por el casting constante entre `int` y `str`:

```
def suma_de_digitos_iterativa(num):
    while num > 9:
        suma = 0
        while num:
            suma, num = suma + num % 10, num // 10
        num = suma
    return num


numero = int(input("Digite un numero que desee que se sume sus digitos: "))
print(suma_de_digitos_iterativa(numero))
```

**Ejemplos:**

> Digite un numero que desee que se sume sus digitos: 2424
>   3
>
> Digite un numero que desee que se sume sus digitos: 458759545485
>   6
>
> Digite un numero que desee que se sume sus digitos: 75124365485544
>   9