# Sumar operar con los valores de diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

Quiero hacer un pequeño conversor de letras a numeros (tipo cifrado).
he creado un diccionario con cada letra, asignandole un valor.
La intencion es que el usuario escriba una palabra y el programa traduzca las letras a numeros, lo sume y devuelva el resultado.

El codigo que tengo es este:

```
codigo = {
    ' ': ' ',
    'A': '1', 
    'B': '2', 
    'C': '2', 
    'D': '4', 
    'E': '5', 
    'F': '8', 
    'G': '3', 
    'H': '8', 
    'I': '1', 
    'J': '1', 
    'K': '2', 
    'L': '3', 
    'M': '4', 
    'N': '5', 
    'O': '7', 
    'P': '8', 
    'Q': '1', 
    'R': '2', 
    'S': '3', 
    'T': '4', 
    'U': '6', 
    'V': '6', 
    'W': '6', 
    'X': '6', 
    'Y': '1', 
    'Z': '7', }


def convertir(frase):
    frase = frase.upper()
    encoded = ""
    for caracter in frase:
        encoded += codigo[caracter] + " " 
    return encoded

frase = input("Escribe una o varias palabras: ")
encoded = convertir(frase)

print(encoded)
```

Y al ejecutarlo consigo que transforme las palabras en numeros. Por ejemplo, si escribo hola me devuelve:

> Escribe una o varias palabras: hola 8 7 3 1

Pero no se como hacer para que realice la suma.
Intuyo que tengo que convertirlo a enteros y entonces sumarlos, pero no se como hacerlo.

Lo que deseo que realice es la correspondiente suma
8+7+3+1 = 19
analice el resultado (19) y vuelva a sumarlo (1 + 9)

Agradezco cualquier aporte.

Comment: no deberias de tenr problemas parseandolo y luego sumandolos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Tienes algun ejemplo de codigo que me ayude a visualizarlo? Gracias

Comment: Puedes hacer simplemente `suma = sum(int(c) for c in encoded)` pero el espacio no se puede convertir a entero, en todo caso debería ser  `' ': '0'`.

Comment: Esta pregunta creo que va por la línea de lo que buscas más o menos : [¿Como sumar los dígitos de 1 numero y seguir sumando si esta suma aun tiene mas de 1 dígito?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/144004/15089)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes iterar los caracteres de un String, en particular de tu variable `encoded`, con un bucle `for`

```
sum = 0
for c in encoded:
  sum += int(c)
```

o de manera más concisa mediante `map` (parseo de String a int) y `reduce` (para sumar)

```
result = reduce(
  lambda x,y: x+y, 
  map(lambda c: int(c), encoded)
)
```

Comment: Gracias Jorge, voy a investigar estos metodos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que quieres reducir todo a una sola cifra, sumando las cifras y después volviendo a sumar, hasta que quede solo una, resulta que la operación que intentas es equivalente a calcular el **módulo 9**, es decir, el resto de la división por 9. Puedes comprobarlo con tu ejemplo 8731. Sumando las cifras sale 19, sumando de nuevo sale 10, y sumando una vez más para dejarlo en una sola cifra, sale 1. Justamente lo mismo que el resto de 8731 entre 9.

Así que aprovechándonos de este hecho basta convertir la cadena "8 7 3 1" a entero y calcular el módulo 9 (`% 9`).

Sería así:

```
cifra = int(encoded.replace(" ", "")) % 9
```

Lo del replace es para eliminar los espacios entre cifras que tenías.